# Can I add feedback (notch) to a gesture on iOS using 3D Touch?

Tags: ios, macos, 3dtouch, force-touch

With Force Touch on OS X applications can provide a feedback or a notch (haptics/taptics?) like Apple's example describes:

> Map rotation: You'll feel a notch when you rotate the compass to north
>   in Maps.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352

Is the the same thing possible with 3D Touch beyond just the old audio API to vibrate the device (AudioServicesPlayAlertSound)?

Comment: Looks like `NSHapticFeedbackPerformer` is OS X only. So maybe not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [UIFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator#2555460) in iOS 10+ on supported devices you could do something like this:

```
var feedbackGenerator: UISelectionFeedbackGenerator

func prepare() {
    // Instantiate a new generator.
    feedbackGenerator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()

    // Prepare the generator when the gesture begins.
    feedbackGenerator?.prepare()
}

func notch() {
    // Trigger selection feedback.
    feedbackGenerator?.selectionChanged()

    // Release the current generator.
    feedbackGenerator = nil
}
```